# Calling & creating new columns based on string

Tags: r, variables, dataframe

I have searched quite a bit and not found a question that addresses this issue--but if this has been answered, forgive me, I am still quite green when it comes to coding in general. I have a data frame with a large number of variables that I would like to combine & create new variables from based on names I've put in a 2nd data frame in a loop. The data frame `formulas` should create & call columns from the main data frame `data`

```
USDb = c(1,2,3)
USDc = c(4,5,6)
EURb = c(7,8,9)
EURc = c(10,11,12)
data = data.frame(USDb, USDc, EURb, EURc)
```

Now I'd like to create a new column `data$USDa` as defined by

```
data$USDa = data$USDb - data$USDc
```

and so on for EUR and other variables. This is easy enough to do manually, but I'd like to create a loop that pulls the names from `formulas`, something like this:

```
a = c("USDa", "EURa")
b = c("USDb", "EURb")
c = c("USDc", "EURc")
formulas = data.frame(a,b,c)

for (i in 1:length(formulas[,a])){
    data$formulas[i,a] = data$formulas[i,b] - data$formulas[i,c]
    }
```

Obviously `data$formulas[i,a]` this returns `NULL`, so I tried `data$paste0(formulas[i,a])` and that returns `Error: attempt to apply non-function`

How can I get these strings to be recognized as variables in this way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

logic : iterate through each of the formulae, using a `apply` which is a `for` loop internally, and do calculation based on the formula

```
x = apply(formulas, 1, function(x) data[[x[3]]] - data[[x[2]]])
colnames(x) = formulas$a
x
#     USDa EURa
#[1,]    3    3
#[2,]    3    3
#[3,]    3    3

cbind(data, x)
#  USDb USDc EURb EURc USDa EURa
#1    1    4    7   10    3    3
#2    2    5    8   11    3    3
#3    3    6    9   12    3    3
```

Comment: yes, this solution worked on the actual data I have and to me seems more elegant than looping. Thank you for the guidance.

Answer (score 1):

There are simpler ways to do this, but I'll stick to most of your code as a means of explanation. Your code should work so long as you edit your for loop to the following:

```
for (i in 1:length(formulas[,"a"])){
    data[formulas[i,"a"]] = data[formulas[i,"b"]] - data[formulas[i,"c"]]
}
```

1. `formulas[,a]` won't work because you have a variable defined as `a` already that is not appropriate inside an index. Use `formulas[, "a"]` instead if you want all rows from column "a" in data.frame `formulas`.
2. `data$formulas` is literally searching for the column called "formulas" in the data.frame `data`. Instead you want to write `data[formulas]`(of course, knowing that you need to index `formulas` in order to make it a proper string)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `split` with `sapply`

```
sapply(setNames(split.default(as.matrix(formulas[-1]), 
   row(formulas[-1])), formulas$a), function(x) Reduce(`-`, data[rev(x)]))
#     USDa EURa
#[1,]    3    3
#[2,]    3    3
#[3,]    3    3
```